# Best tutorial for Ruboto (ruby for Android)?

Tags: ruby, ruboto

I'm almost done with Ruby but now want to try my hands on Ruboto, ruby on android.
Google failed to give me sufficient (almost no results).So can anyone please share some tutorials on Ruboto.

Comment: There are indeed very few resources when it comes to ruboto right now.
It seems to me that the target audience for this project is people who already know android development in java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the looks of it, Ruboto's own documentation is still under development! Ruboto's GitHub Wiki provides some tutorials and examples, but they're not totally complete. However, this may be enough to get you started. Be sure to read the README (which is also available on their GitHub Wiki):

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/blob/master/README.md

That should get you set up to go through their own tutorials:

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorials-and-examples

As Ivaylo Strandjev has already said, what you'll really need to learn to make apps with Ruboto is a sufficient knowledge of Ruby. From there, Ruboto is simply extending Ruby's capabilities to communicate with Android. Understanding how it does so is all you need!

You're right, though! There aren't a lot of tutorials, yet, because Ruboto is still a very early effort. Provided you have a good knowledge of Ruby, however, these tutorials and a thorough reading of Ruboto's documentation on GitHub should be more than enough to get your feet wet.

Happy Rubying!

Answer (score 2):

Ruboto now supports a lot of ruby's functionality and also there are some examples included on how to do "more fancy stuff". Still so far all the programs I have written in **ruby** work on ruboto too. So my suggestion is - find a ruby tutorial instead.

Comment: I have done ruby! I'll have to see then how ruby communicates with android.